# Webpack - devtools in configuration for production

Tags: webpack

so I'm trying to setting up now the webpack configuration for my production mode, and I just can't understand why would I use devtools at production.

Devtools are meant to make your life easier while debugging, but why would I need this on production? 
And if I do need it, which one should I use?

Answer (score 3):

For most setups out there, you would not want to use `devtools` in production, because you don't support debugging for clients accessing the production hosts.

However, without source maps it would be impossible to make use of stack traces for runtime errors in minified production sources if someone would be able to produce them. You usually rely on knowing the file, location, identifiers and error messages for debugging, but all of this information may be discarded with  optimizations. With `{devtools: 'hidden-source-map'}`, you produce source maps along with your builds. The bare minimum you can do is make the source maps for the current live build available somewhere in case a developer needs to troubleshoot dumps. A better setup would be to run with a particular error reporter that flushes stacks to a backend that integrates them with source maps.

It can be useful if you really do want to provide easy source debugging, say showing off source code on your personal website. Since they are usually several times larger than your optimized sources, you can opt to provide them as separate files which are downloaded only when users open their developer tools, so use `{devtools: 'source-map'}`.